# AppDynamics module not found in NodeJS app contained in Docker? MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, appdynamics

Is there a known issue with yarn pkg manager and appdynamics 21.8. I am having these show up in my cloudwatch logs . I have ensured that my appdynamics appears in the external array in my webpack.config.js file. I can run locally but run into issues when I try to push to the cloud.

```
2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   throw err;

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   ^

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   Error: Cannot find module 'appdynamics'

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   Require stack:

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   - /usr/nodejs/app/main.js

2021-10-08T10:18:28.150-05:00   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at Object.appdynamics (/usr/nodejs/app/main.js:316910:18)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at __webpack_require__ (/usr/nodejs/app/main.js:20:30)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at Object../src/index.ts (/usr/nodejs/app/main.js:304430:23)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at __webpack_require__ (/usr/nodejs/app/main.js:20:30)

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at /usr/nodejs/app/main.js:84:18

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/nodejs/app/main.js:87:10) {

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   requireStack: [ '/usr/nodejs/app/main.js' ]

2021-10-08T10:18:28.151-05:00   }
```

This is my docker file:

```
FROM <remoteRepo> AS unittest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/nodejs/app
WORKDIR /usr/nodejs/app

COPY . .

# Install Dependencies and Test
RUN rm -rf node_modules/
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn coverage
FROM <remoteRepo> AS builder

COPY --from=unittest . .
WORKDIR /usr/nodejs/app

RUN yarn build

FROM <RemoteRepo>

RUN apk add --update \
    python3 \
    jq \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade awscli \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/nodejs/app
WORKDIR /usr/nodejs/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/nodejs/app/build/ /usr/nodejs/app/

EXPOSE 8080

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

I am new to docker and am unsure where to start with this bug?
Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried looking into the docker image whether appdynamics exists in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @st.huber I am unable to add the appdynamcis module into the docker image itself as these images being used are immutable. I I need to figure out a way to integrate the module into the app or sidecare.

Comment: Take a look in your package.json. Does it have "appdynamics" in the "dependencies"? If so, then you have to (1) have it in your docker image or (2) have an entrypoint script that installs those dependencies. However, you already run `yarn install` in your docker build, why don't you copy the productive node_modules over to your final image or use  `yarn install --production` in your other image build? [See here for yarn2 cmd](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration/#renamed)